# Asynchronously fetching new resources from the response of a previous request inside a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add the notable residents's names listed for every planet that is clicked using this API: https://swapi.dev/

I tried doing it at the bottom of the Planet detail page, but it is not working.
The notable residents are links to other API resources, and I don't know how to deal with them.

ERROR:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
PlanetDetail.render
C:/Users/charl/Desktop/IRONHACK/Paperbox/paperbox/src/pages/Planetdetail.js:75
  72 |     )}
  73 | </div>
  74 | <div>
> 75 |         <h1>Notable people</h1>
     | ^  76 |         {
  77 |             this.state.planetInfo.residents.map(resident => 
  78 |                 <p>{resident.name}</p>
```

---

**HOME.JS**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"

class Home extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            planets: [],
            filteredPlanets: []
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(e){ // eslint-disable-next-line
        let planetssearchlist = this.state.planets.filter(planet => {
             if(planet.name){
                if(planet.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())){
                    return true 
                }   
            }
        })
        this.setState({
            filteredPlanets: planetssearchlist
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/"
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.results)
            let planetslist = response.data.results;
            this.setState({planets: planetslist, filteredPlanets: planetslist})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("You've made an error with the planets load charles: ",error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (

        <div>
            <h1>Star Wars Planets</h1>

            <form>
                <input placeholder="searchbar" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
            </form>

            {
                this.state.filteredPlanets.map((planet,i) => (
                    <Link to={{ pathname: "/info", state:{planet:planet} }}><p key={i}>{planet.name}</p></Link>
                ))   
            }

        </div>    

        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

---

**PLANETDETAIL.JS**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class PlanetDetail extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            url: "",
            planetInfo: {},
            isGettingPlanetInfo: false
        };
    }

  getPlanetInfo = () => {
    this.setState({
      isGettingPlanetInfo: true
    });

    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: this.state.url
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({
          planetInfo: response.data,
          isGettingPlanetInfo: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          isGettingPlanetInfo: false
        });
        console.log(
          "You've made an error with the planet detail load charles: ",error
        );
      });
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        url: this.props.location.state.planet.url
      },
      this.getPlanetInfo
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <div>
            {this.state.isGettingPlanetInfo ? 
            (<p>Getting planet info...</p>) :
            typeof this.state.planetInfo === "object" && Object.keys(this.state.planetInfo).length ? 
            (  
            <div>
                <h1>Planet details</h1>
                <p>planet name: {this.state.planetInfo.name}</p>
                <p>rotation period: {this.state.planetInfo.rotation_period}</p>
                <p>orbital period: {this.state.planetInfo.orbital_period}</p>
                <p>diameter: {this.state.planetInfo.diameter}</p>
                <p>climate: {this.state.planetInfo.climate}</p>
                <p>gravity: {this.state.planetInfo.gravity}</p>
                <p>terrain: {this.state.planetInfo.terrain}</p>
                <p>surface water: {this.state.planetInfo.surface_water}</p>
                <p>population: {this.state.planetInfo.population}</p>
            </div>
            ) : (
            ""
            )}
        </div>
        <div>
                <h1>Notable people</h1>
                {
                    this.state.planetInfo.residents.map(resident => 
                        <p>{resident.url}</p>   
                    )
                }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PlanetDetail
```

Comment: `<p>{resident.url}</p>` – why not `{resident.name}` instead? Or some other property besides the url?

Comment: I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Can you add your exact and entire error to your question? If have a sandbox or example of this working in context, that would be helpful in finding what's wrong.

Comment: added the entire error!

Comment: @ThomasUpton: could you please have another look?

Comment: `planetInfo.residents` isn't defined, meaning that it's not in the response as expected. You're logging the response: what does it tell you is there in terms of `residents`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using state to set the url to fetch for planet details, `planetInfo` won't be populated in your initial render. You're already guarding against this for the other planet info, so do the same for the residents section by putting it under the same conditional.

You need to actually fetch the resident details – they aren't part of the planet response. I'd abstract that into a new component. [Here's a Codepen of such a component](https://codepen.io/tupton/pen/yLeLwPg?editors=0010).

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {this.state.isGettingPlanetInfo ? (
          <p>Getting planet info...</p>
        ) : typeof this.state.planetInfo === "object" &&
          Object.keys(this.state.planetInfo).length ? (
          <>
            <div>
              <h1>Planet details</h1>
              <p>planet name: {this.state.planetInfo.name}</p>
              <p>rotation period: {this.state.planetInfo.rotation_period}</p>
              <p>orbital period: {this.state.planetInfo.orbital_period}</p>
              <p>diameter: {this.state.planetInfo.diameter}</p>
              <p>climate: {this.state.planetInfo.climate}</p>
              <p>gravity: {this.state.planetInfo.gravity}</p>
              <p>terrain: {this.state.planetInfo.terrain}</p>
              <p>surface water: {this.state.planetInfo.surface_water}</p>
              <p>population: {this.state.planetInfo.population}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
<h1>Notable people</h1>;
{
  this.state.planetInfo.residents.map(<Resident url={resident} />);
}
            </div>
          </>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
// Resident.js
const Resident = ({ url }) => {
  const [resident, setResident] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchResident = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios({
          method: "GET",
          url
        });
        setResident(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error retrieving resident", error);
      }
    };
    fetchResident();
  }, [url]);
  return resident ? (
    <div>
      <span>{resident.name}</span>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>Fetching resident...</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: The goal is that I would indeed not see the url but the name of the person to which the url is linking. Each url link to a specific name:  "residents": [
  "http://swapi.dev/api/people/5/",
  "http://swapi.dev/api/people/68/",
  "http://swapi.dev/api/people/81/"
 ],

Comment: any idea? or no clue?

Comment: @Charlinhovdb you need to fetch those urls, just like you do for the planet info. I added an example of how I'd do it.